# Do I need to provide a date of departure to apply to a EEA Family Permit in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am a French citizen, married to a Russian citizen, and I live in the UK. She is now filling the application for a family permit, to join me, and once there, she will apply to a residence card to stay permanently with me.

During the application for the family permit, they ask for a duration of stay:

```
How long do you intend to stay in the UK? 
On which date will you leave the UK?
```

What should she answer to that? A stay of 6 month (the duration of the visa)?

Also, the form asks if she intends to work in the UK. But if she answers "yes", could it look suspicious to the agent?

Comment: I will let someone more knowledgeable about all this provide more details in an answer but being deceptive is a very bad idea and her intents will be easy to guess when looking at the whole picture so don't try to present this as a short-time trip. My guess is that those questions are there because the same form can be used for short-term travel by relatives of EU citizens who do not reside in the UK.

Comment: @Gala indeed, the form is poorly constructed. I completed an EEA family permit application for my mother in law with my wife as the sponsor and it asked all sorts of inappropriate (and borderline offensive) questions intended for spouses like whether they had any children together.  There were similarly lots of questions that were inappropriate given the free movement directive such as questions about income and, indeed, details of travel plans and accommodation. Questions relevant only to short trips didn't stand out, since it was a short trip, but I'm sure they were there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those questions form part of all the applications in the category of visas that expire in 6 months or less.  [Gala](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/60/gala) (to whom thanks) has pointed out that everyone gets those questions.  How the ECO treats the answers depends upon the applicant's premise.

They are not going to be overly concerned about it on a family permit because they expect the applicant to be applying for a residence card anyway.

For the question "How long do you intend to stay in the UK?" you can write "indefinite" or "settlement" or "n/a" or even "six months" if you feel uncomfortable.  It's a free form text field and you can put anything that makes sense.

For the question "On which date will you leave the UK?", it's a date field and subject to edits by the software.  You can enter any appropriate date, but if you answered the previous question with "indefinite", then you should enter the expiry date of your current passport - - It's important not to enter anything beyond that date.